# Connecting to Oracle via a TNS name and oracledb - module not found

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I want to create a js file that connects to oracle via a tnsnames.ora file.

Here's my code:

```
const oracledb = require('C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\oracledb');

const connection = oracledb.getConnection({
  connectString:"TNS_ADMIN\Test_db"
})

console.log(connection)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\myuser>node otest.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\oracledb'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\myuser\otest.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myuser\otest.js:1:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\otest.js' ]
}

Node.js v18.16.1
```

- I have installed oracledb globally

### Why can't node find oracledb?

Comment: Try `const oracledb = require('oracledb');`.  And then read the [doc on connection string formats](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-strings) - a hint is that you don't put TNS_ADMIN in the connection string; and commonly you would include a username & password.  Check the [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/main/examples).

Comment: @ChristopherJones. I was hoping using the un/pw in the tns would allow it to be used for oracledb since the pw changes every month. Anyway, using simply `oracledb` didn't work either. Maybe I installed it wrong? `npm install -g oracledb`

Comment: With node-oracledb, to use un/pw credentials you need to use separate `user` and `password` attributes in the `getConnection()` option.  You cannot say 'un/pw@hostname/servicename'.  See all the examples such as the first one in https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#easy-connect-syntax-for-connection-strings